# Re-scanning existing files stored in internal memory in android using java

Tags: java, android, excel

I have created an excel file in a folder through my app. By making use of-

```
    File f4=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),foldername+"/"+filename);
    new SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this,f4.getAbsolutePath());
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+foldername+"/"+filename)));
```

I am able to trigger a media scan and hence view the refreshed and newly created excel sheet on my desktop, when I connect my phone.

But when I delete the excel sheet, make some changes and recreate the excel sheet in the same folder and with the same name (all done through my app), if I use the same code to trigger a media scan, the size changes in the excel sheet are not updated.

Can someone please help me to update and refresh to show size changes as well?

Comment: FYI, re-scanning works fine if I create the excel sheet with a different file name.